# Is multivariate GLM significantly different from univariate GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis

**Question:** Is the theory of multivariate GLMs significantly different from the theory of univariate GLMs? If ou want to learn the latter, do you learn univariate GLM first and then specialize, or do you learn multivariate directly?

Comment: I wouldn't call going from the univariate to the multivariate "specializing"; that would be generalizng (going to the more general case from a more special case).

Comment: What does GLM stand for? "General linear model" or "generalized linear model"? The first refers to normal linear models while the latter refers to non-normal models. If you really mean non-normal models, then what multivariate generalized linear model did you have in mind? I can only think of one or two examples of multivariate non-normal generalized linear models, and they don't get a lot of practical application. Multinomial logit models can be viewed as multivariate generalized linear models, but they are usually analysed using Poisson log-linear models.

Comment: @Gordon I was going to ask the same question before I posted my answer, but then I noticed the OP had chosen the tag "generalized linear model" -- so presumably that's the intended case. While they're considerably more rarely used, Fahrmeir and Tutz did a whole book on Multivariate GLMs and there's an R package called `Fahrmeir` for fitting them (maintained by regular CV contributor Kjetil B. Halvorsen)

Comment: @Barel your title asks a somewhat different question from your body text (and the title question would be hard to answer unless you specified what "significantly different" might consist of)

Comment: @Glen_b I saw the tag also, but a poster who doesn't know generalized linear models might naturally think that "generalized linear models" is a synonym for "general linear models". That often happens, for example: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264058/glm-equation-in-rJudging

Comment: @gordon Yes, that does sometimes happen.

Comment: One (other) R package that might be useful is `VGAM`, vector generalized linear models.  That is a huge package (with a corresponding book) and it implements a class of models which is HUGE, hugely extending multivariate glm's

Answer (score 2):

It's generally easier for humans to learn something that's conceptually simpler and then use the understanding as a basis to generalize in some way than to start with the most general case.

If you're trying to learn multivariate GLMs, I'd definitely start with univariate; there's plenty of new ideas there without the additional effort of a multivariate response.

This is nearly always the way generalized linear models are taught, start with univariate GLMs (indeed many people never touch the multivariate case, but if they do it's nearly always after having learned the univariate generalized linear model). This is no accident.

For that matter (given the discussion comments), I'd say the same thing about general linear models (or indeed almost anything else) -- univariate first, then worry about multivariate.